# Is there an alternative to the camera.capture_continuous() function provided by PiCamera for PiCamera2

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, migration, picamera

I am trying to migrate a codebase from using picamera to picamera2. The current code snippet is:

```
stream = io.BytesIO()
for _ in camera.capture_continuous(stream, format='jpeg', use_video_port=True):
   stream.seek(0)
   image = Image.open(stream).convert('RGB')
```

I can't find anything in the documentation for picamera2 that points to an alternative for the capture_continuous function. I even tried looking up picamera's documentation to try to understand how the capture_continuous function works to no avail.